# Feasibility of an android messaging system using MQTT protocol

Tags: android, messaging, publish-subscribe, mqtt

Is such a system feasible?

Can we implement features like: (all)

1. User Access Control.
2. Encryption of messages transferred.
3. Predefined Topics.
4. Message Logging(in a Database)
5. Support up to 1000 users in the system.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feasible? Sure. None of the features you mentioned will really be in Android though, they'll be in your backend.

Comment: How so? is it possible to manipulate the usage of MQTT to support all these functionalities from the backend? Given the protocol has an inherent limitation(i.e. Only msg transfer)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but the fact that you're using MQTT doesn't change much conceptually. You have a client and you have a server. You need to communicate between the two whether that's directly with TCP/UDP, XML/JSON web services, or in your case MQTT. The fact that you're using MQTT has little to no impact on the feature set that you mentioned, only on implementation, performance characteristics, etc. As an example of an Android messaging system using MQTT, you can see [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/building-facebook-messenger/10150259350998920).

Comment: Facebook was able to achieve that using their custom MQTT server. Does the common open source Mosquitto server handle the support of these features?

Comment: Again, other than #5 and perhaps #2, none of these features have anything to do with your message transport mechanism. For #2, either your transport encrypts the message or you can send a message that has already been encrypted.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at these in relation to MQTT

- User Access Control - handled by the broker, via a username/password on the CONNECT call. Implementations vary. IBM's commercial WMQ product provides a pluggable mechanism for auth, not sure about open source ones. If you want to encrypt the wire using SSL you could do so, again the commercial IBM implementation supports that, I don't believe the free options do.
- Encryption of messages - needs to be done in the app, MQTT doesn't care what the payload is. There's [some discussion of this online](http://false.ekta.is/tag/mqtt/).
- Predefined Topics - you define the topics your app uses and decide how to use them! there's no need to "predefine" anything from an administrative perspective.
- Message Logging - simple to do via a backend script to subscribe to topics and push into a DB.
- Support up to 1000 users - depends on the implementation, but yes. Again the commercial IBM implementation supports tens of thousands of concurrent connections, the free RSMB is limited to (I think) ~1100 connections... of course that's a count of connections rather than users.

I hope that helps. There's a good MQTT community at mqtt.org and mailing list available via mqtt.org/get-involved. There's a [good news post discussing places where MQTT is being used on Android](http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-and-android-make-great-partners), too.